# Undefined name 'DefaultfirebaseOptions'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I Got This Weird Error:

"Undefined name 'DefaultfirebaseOptions' "

````
@override 
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Register"),
        ), 
      body:FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultfirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
          ),
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:```
````

Comment: You have a capitalization typo: `DefaultfirebaseOptions` should be `DefaultFirebaseOptions` with an uppercase `F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up Firebase on your project. Start with `firebase init`

Follow this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)

You will get similar to this

[image]

then import the file